# How to manage hierarchy in the new modern SharePoint with hubsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, modern-team-site, hub-site

I am currently developing a solution with real estate and I need a solid SharePoint hierarchy so manage this.

Every real estate has an owner/owners and Contractors so it would look like this in a classic SharePoint.

**[SiteCollections]InternalWeb-> [SubSite]Owner-> [SubSite]Real Estate -> [SubSite]Contractors**

And the real estate SubSites have like 30 pages that are identical for every owners/real estate it's just the web part showing different data depending on term store. So to manage this they all use the same library of pages so the maintenance of those pages is simple.

The thing is that owner can have like 20 real estates and now with the "Flat" SharePoint experience this hierarchy will of real estates cant be done without giving us a lot of work hours to maintain.

***So my first thought about this is as follow***

**[Hub Site]Internal Web -> [SiteCollection]Every Real Estate (About 100 of them) -> [SitePages]About 30 pages for each real estate**

We have Azure Ad security group for every real estate so the security part is pretty simple.

We would use an SPFX top navigation as navbar targeting specific term store, but also that will need a lot of hours to maintain.

I have read some of the SharedNavigation but it feels like that is targeting smaller areas with hub site.

So my big question here is this the right way to go or is there some fancy feature I have missed out to manage this SharePoint hierarchy in the new modern SharePoint?